# Can I change shape of a rigid body after it created in Bullet3D?

Tags: physics, bullet-physics

I'm beginning Bullet3D. Can I change collision shape of a rigid body after it created? A rigid body accepts a collision shape when it's creating, but it's hard to find options changes the collision shape of an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are `setCollisionShape()` and `setMassProps()` method for this on `btRigidBody` class.

Comment: `setCollisionShape` doesn't appear in the [documentation](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtRigidBody.html), except in a code snippet as a private method -- is the documentation out of date or just missing that method?

Comment: @Josh This is completely my guessing. I don't think the `BulletPhysics` have well reference document. (except user guide) Because there are some mismatch points in doc against real code, and there're many people complaining about its doc quality. And even the author confirmed it. It's obvious the doc is not syncing with recent code. IMHO, the author does not care about documentation so much. So I just followed the rule "Source is the documentation" as like many open-source projects. I don't like this kind of hacking, but I believe that the author may don't have enough time to manage to doc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't. You'd have swap out the entire rigid body object, I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've been able to do it:

1. Remove the rigidbody from the world.
2. Destroy the old shape(not sure if this is needed, but I do it for safe measure).
3. Create the newShape.
4. Use rigidbody.setCollisionShape(newShape).  It is on the btRigidbody but is not in the API because it is an inherited from btCollisionObject.
5. newShape.calculateLocalInertia(mass, inertia).
6. rigidbody.setMassProps(mass, inertia).
7. rigidbody.updateInertiaTensor().
8. re-add the rigidbody to the world.

Depending on if your object is kinematic or has 0 mass, you might not need to do all the steps above, but I included them just in case.